# clickhouse sql division with decimal

Tags: clickhouse

how to avoid DB::Exception: Division by zero in clickhouse when I use `divide(Decimal v1,Decimal v2)` and v2 comes from a subquery. I tried to use `case when v2 = 0 then 0 else divide end` but didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in recent CH versions

```sql
SELECT if(b = toDecimal64(0, 10), toDecimal64(0, 10), a / b) AS res
FROM
(
    SELECT
        materialize(toDecimal64(1, 10)) AS a,
        materialize(toDecimal64(0, 10)) AS b
)

┌─res─┐
│   0 │
└─────┘
```